# How do I conditionally render a link in a visualforce page based on the logged in user

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to conditionally show a Link on a visualforce page based on the logged in users profile.  I can't seem to get this to work.

```
<apex:outputLink rendered="{!IF($User.ProfileId == "00e38000001FkY3AAK",true,false)}" value="https://devtest-wkfs.cs77.force.com/OneSumXFRRSupport/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01538000002CZbR"/>
```

Comment: try changing the double quotes around the profileId to single quotes and also change the `==` to `=` so: `"{!IF($User.ProfileId = '00e38000001FkY3AAK',true,false)}"`

Comment: I made these changes, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Try with the 15 char Id instead of the 18 char (Case Sensitive) 
If that doesn't work, try comparing the `$Profile.Name` instead of the `$User.ProfileId`

Comment: What happens if you just output the profileId to the page?  This is troubleshooting 101.

Comment: I am new to visualforce so I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Z33dawg - I tried changing to the 15 char and that didn't work so I tried changing the criteria to $Profile.Name and that didn't work either.

Comment: @Nick Cook means just display the merge field on the page and see what value it outputs. 
ex: just write -->   ProfileId : {!$User.ProfileId} and then load your page. See what the value is.
consider doing this logged in as a user with the profileId of interest.